# Layout desconfigurado no android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Boa noite!
Estou começando meus estudo com Android Studio.
Montei meu layout mas quando vou simular ele no simulador do Android Studio, ele aparece todo desconfigurado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom provavelmente seu layout não está "parent" poste o xml do designer que fica mais fácil te ajudar

Comment: Bem provável que você esteja usando o `<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout ...>` muda para `<RelativeLayout...>` ai ira funcionar, depois só colocar os itens na posição desejavel...

Comment: Por favor, poste o source do layout.

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema que o seu, comecei semana passada, dei uma pesquisa e é "bem simples" essa parte, recomendo você ler a documentação do [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor?hl=pt-br) me ajudou bastante, e eu recomendo esse [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YCUrHFUxlA) no youtube que também me ajudou muito.